# Print ordem inversa

Tags: python

Dado um numero x, onde 1000≤x<10000, imprima o numero x com seus dígitos na ordem inversa. 
Por exemplo: x = 2736, a resposta será 6372.

```
x=float(input()) 
x=float(x)
if (x >= 1000 and x < 10000):  
print("%.f"%x)
```

Não consigo fazer ele ficar da ordem inversa, ou seja se ele entra com o numero 1234 sai 1234 e não 4321 como deveria...como faço?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
x = float(input()) 
if (x >= 1000 and x < 10000):  
  y = str(x)
  print(y[::-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Segue uma função para realizar a inversão:

```
def reverse_number(n):
  r = 0
  while n > 0:
    r *= 10
    r += n % 10
    n /= 10
  return r
```

Comment: Ok, mas tem como você editar a minha?queria aprender melhor do ponto que eu fiz...teria como?grato

Comment: Your output:
0.5658
Correct output:
5658

Comment: Ta certinho porem tem um 0. que nao pode ter, como tira?

Comment: Ao invés de usar float você deveria usar int

Comment: Muito obrigado vcs são mitos